# How to make a redirect in nodejs from front end browser app request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, paypal

I have an app with nodejs as backend and angularjs as frontend.

From my browser I post a request to node to  make a paypal payment.
Something as `$htpp.post('/makepayment', cart)`.

The problem is that paypal api, needs to call a "res.redirect" and It causes a CORS Origin problem, since I am make the request from my angular frontend app.
I have CORS settings im my node server, but, off course, it will do no difference in respect to my problem because the redirect make a request to paypal.

The error is:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-YYYYYY: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How could I do it without have this CORS problem?

In NodeJs I have this route with the code:

```
router.post('/makepayment', (req, res) => {
  const create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://localhost/paypal/success",
        "cancel_url": "http://localhost/paypal/cancel"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "Red Sox Hat",
                "sku": "001",
                "price": "25.00",
                "currency": "BRL",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "BRL",
            "total": "25.00"
        },
        "description": "Hat for the best team ever"
    }]
};

paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
  if (error) {
      throw error;
  } else {
      for(let i = 0;i < payment.links.length;i++){
        if(payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url'){
          res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
        }
      }
  }
});
```